# Passing props to instances mounted on existing markup and created with Vue.extend

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

I want to substitute parts of a website with instances of Vue. One of those instances is a simple countdown. I use the following syntax to create an instance:

```
const Countdown = Vue.extend({

....

});
```

Then, in a main file I initialize the countdown the following way, manually mounting it to the existing markup:

```
const instance = new Countdown();

instance.$mount('.js-countdown');
```

The markup is just a simple div that has other elements inside:

```
<div class="counter js-countdown"> ... </div>
```

My question is am I able to pass props to my countdown like I could have down it with a custom component, since it is a root of the instance:

```
<div class="counter js-countdown" hours="2"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass it the `propsData` in the options:

```js
const instance = new Countdown({
    propsData: { hours: 2 }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This helps in some cases. But what if I have a computed attribute? For example, 

`<div start-time="{{ helpers.getTimestamp() }}"> ... </div>`

I am using nunjucks template engine.